# register and view events with action in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have a search textbox in my site and when a user stops typing I register an event (search, txt value),
in Universal Analytics I was calling it like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'search', txtValue)
```

in GA4 I tried doing this:

```
gtag('event', 'search', { action: txtValue });
```

and the event gets registered, but nowhere in the GA4 reporting can I find how to see the registered events with action table, something like this:

```
(event = 'search')
action    | count
txt val 1 | 32
txt val 2 | 5
txt val 3 | 1
```

in UA I wold just go to `Events` -> click on 'search' event -> and select 'action' for 2nd dimension,

how do I get this report now ?
or should I register the event in some other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to make custom dimensions for your event parameters to become available. Similarly to GA UA:

Admin -> Custom Definitions -> Create custom dimension

Now just make a CD for your `action` property.

Good, now go to the Explore NOT Reports. Reports are now pretty much useless.
In Explore, make a new exploration, add your new `action` custom dimension there as a dimension. Also add the event name as a dimension. Add something like `sessions` as a metric.

Now drag and drop the items you've added into the `tab setting` column and you should be able to access your data now. It's a clumsy interface for sure, but it works. You can as well add a filter there to only include the search events in case you want to reuse that event property in other events.

Note! that google has now introduced this all new and shiny cardinality limitation on your dimensions. So if you get over 500 unique search values in that custom dimensions, well, read this: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12226705?hl=en

UA was too good to be free. They "fixed" it in GA4 :)

Comment: looks promising, except I'm getting (not set) values for the "action" column; I've added custom definition "action" (scope: event, user property: action)

Comment: great, then confirm that you're actually setting it by inspecting the network calls and seeing whether they contain the `ep.action` field

Comment: I see a `collect` request with: `en: menu search, ep.action: how are you, ..` ( "how are  you" is what I wrote in the textbox to trigger the event);
perhaps I need to wait 1 day for the explore table to start showing data instead of (not set)

Comment: ye. free GA4 asks for 2 days of time allowance before accessing the data.

Comment: the data with `action` custom parameter is being collected for months already, but the custom defintion and the exploration was created today

Comment: still getting `(not set)` for the action column(dimension) in the exploration

Comment: Check that the tid in the Network request matches your property's data stream's measurement id. Maybe you're sending data into a wrong property.

Comment: the `tid: value` in the collect request matches the `MEASUREMENT ID` of the 1 data stream that I have

Comment: Ok, that's odd. We could export the data into BQ and see how it looks there. That would exclude any UI issues of the Explorer. Before we go that route, however, make sure your definition of the custom dimension is correct. Like that the parameter is not misspelled. Also make sure that that CD is the one you're pulling into the Explore. Maybe you've made a few and you're looking at the wrong one. Make a screenshot of your Explore view and add to the question. Maybe you're missing a metric there, have a poorly set filter or wrong date range. Also fix your data retention setting. Default is poor.

Comment: now If I go to sidemenu -> Engagement -> Events -> click on `search` event, I get the report that I wanted in a rectangle titled `eventAction` (eventAction being the name of my custom definition), and in its table (Custom parameter | event count | total users) I can see for each custom parameter value how many times (event count) it happened

Comment: Great. You're supposed to be able to use Exploration for this. Reports are... Well, they're not very useful since you can't drill in into them. Very limited analysis can be done there. But until that's enough, you should be good.

Comment: well, in my case the exploration shows `(not set)` for the `eventAction` column

Comment: that probably has something to do with how you pull metrics into it or maybe some filters are the issue.

Comment: There's no filters applied, on a new clean free form I just drag the eventAction DIMENSION to ROWS and I get `No data for this combination of segments, values, filters, and date range. Try editing the variables or settings or remove them.`

Answer (score 0):

1-Open your GA4 property and navigate to "Analysis" in the left-hand menu.
2-Click on "Custom Reports" and then click the "+ NEW CUSTOM REPORT" button.
3-Give your report a name and choose "Table" as the format.
4-In the "Explore" section, click on "Add dimension" and search for the parameter you used for the search text value (in this case, "search_query").
5- Add any additional dimensions or metrics you want to include in the report.
6- Save the report.

This should do it

Keep in mind that GA4 and UA have different data models and structures, so you might need to adapt your reporting approach when transitioning from UA to GA4. Custom reports in GA4 offer a lot of flexibility, allowing you to build the reports that best suit your needs based on the new data model.